# How to read a value from recursive xml attribute in Unix using sed/awk/grep only

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have config.xml. Here I need to retrieve the value of the attribute from the xpath 
/domain/server/name

I can only use grep/sed/awk. Need Help

The content of the xml is below where I need to retrieve the Server Name only.

```
<domain>
    <server>
        <name>AdminServer</name>
        <port>1234</port>
    </server>
    <server>
        <name>M1Server</name>
        <port>5678</port>
    </server>
    <machine>
        <name>machine01</name>
    </machine>
    <machine>
        <name>machine02</name>
    </machine>
</domain>
```

The output should be :

```
AdminServer
M1Server
```

I tried to do,

```
sed -ne '/<\/name>/ { s/<[^>]*>(.*)<\/name>/\1/; p }' config.xml
```

Comment: sed -ne '/<\/name>/ { s/<[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/name>/\1/; p }' config.xml
This command is returning the values from all the name atttributes
AdminServer
M1
machine01
machine02

Comment: We dont have access to those tools. Cant install them

Comment: @jkalyanc, do you have python installed?

Comment: sed -ne '/<server>/,\|</server>|{ s/ <[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/server>/\1/; p }' 
config.xml . On using this command the result is 

<server>
            <name>AdminServer</name>
            <port>1234</port>
          </server>
          <server>
            <name>M1Server</name>
            <port>5678</port>
          </server>

Atleast want to know if i can use this output and fetch the server name?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No we dont have python either. I am actually in a tricky situation

Comment: pretty sad situation with unpredictable consequences

Comment: @Inian My bad. It is M1Server

Comment: @jkalyanc: Can you print `awk --version` and same for `grep` and `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample Input_file shown, could you please try following.

```
awk -F"[><]" '/<\/server>/{a="";next} /<server>/{a=1;next} a && /<name>/{print $3}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

sed is **only** for simple substitutions on individual lines, doing anything else with sed is strictly for mental exercise, not for real code. That's not what you are trying to do so you shouldn't even be considering sed. Just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' 'p=="server" && $2=="name"{print $3} {p=$2}' file
AdminServer
M1Server
```

That will work with any awk on any UNIX box. If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command. Name your xml and supply that file as an input.

```
awk '/<server>/,/<\/server>/' < name.xml | grep "name" | cut -d ">" -f2 | cut -d "<" -f1
```

OutPut:

```
AdminServer
M1Server
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/<server>/{n;s/\s*<[^>]*>//gp}'
```

for example. for the first match

```
1. /<server>/
match the line that contains "<server>" got "     <server>"

2. n
the "n" command will go to next line. after executed "n" command got "        <name>AdminServer</name>"

3.s/\s*<[^>]*>//gp
replece all "\s*<[^>]*>" as "". then print the pattern space
```

type "info sed" for more sed command

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output with just sed:

```
sed -n 's:.*<name>\(.*\)</name>.*:\1:p' config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

[I feel dirty parsing XML in awk.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1072112)

The following finds the correct *depth* of entry with the right tag name. It does not verify the path, though it depends on the elements you specified. While this works on your example data, it makes certain ugly assumptions and it's not guaranteed to work elsewhere:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '$2~/^(domain|server|name)$/{n++} $1~/\// {n--} n==3&&$2=="name"{print $3}' input.xml
```

A better solution would be to parse the XML itself.

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' -v check="domain.server.name" '$2~/^[a-z]/ { path=path "." $2; closex="</"$2">" } $0~closex { sub(/\.[^.]$/,"",path) } substr(path,2)==check {print path " = " $3}' input.xml
.domain.server.name = AdminServer
```

Here it is split out for easier commenting.

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' -v check="domain.server.name" '
  # Split fields around pointy brackets. Supply a path to check.

  $2~/^[a-z]/ {         # If we see an open tag,
    path=path "." $2    # append the current tag to our path,
    closex="</"$2">"    # compose a close tag which we'll check later.
  }

  $0~closex {                   # If we see a close tag,
    sub(/\.[^.]$/,"",path)      # truncate the path.
  }

  substr(path,2)==check {       # If we match the given path,
    print path " = " $3         # print the result.
  }

' input.xml
```

Note that this solution barfs horribly if you feed it badly formatted XML. The recognition of tags could be improved, but may be sufficient if you have consistently formatted XML. It may barf horribly for other reasons too. Do not do this. Install the correct tools to parse XML properly.